# Joining Logs Using Elasticsearch + Kinesis

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I have multiple unique sources of customer logs with primary key eventID, and all sources contain the same eventID's but generate different datapoints on each eventID. For example, eventID Abc123 has the following data in each source:

- User.METADATA

  - eventID: Abc123
  - userIP: 00.000.00.00
  - userStatus: Non-Member
  - userType: Production

---

- Device.METADATA

  - eventID: Abc123
  - deviceID: 112112Adk
  - deviceLocale: US
  - deviceType: 001uus

---

- Event.DATA

  - eventID: Abc123
  - button: true
  - purchase: true
  - dollarAmt: 199.99

Other notes: 1) these logs are generated on separate servers and 2) not every eventID exists in all 3 sources. Some sources may be missing certain eventID's.

How can I parse these three sources with Kinesis and combine them into 1 master JSON object that gets ingested into ES?

Comment: This should be doable with Logstash using a `kinesis` input + an `aggregate` filter + the `elasticsearch` output.

Comment: Can you point me to any resources or tutorials that demonstrate what you're suggesting?